# Rename tab name and object name by Profile or App

Tags: app, tab, object, translation-workbench, label

We have multiple Apps in our Org. App1 could refer Account as Sites,App2 could refer Account as Companies and App3 could refer Account as Account.

I could rename Account under Setup->User Interface->Rename Tabs and Labels but it will effect all Apps or Profiles.

How could I rename object name or tab name by Profile or App.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've heard that this is something that's coming in the future, but you can't do this today.

Comment: @sfdcfox There is an idea but I don't see any updates on this from Salesforce product team. https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Bq3XAAS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Winter 17, its not possible to rename tabs,object,field based on profile.There is an idea

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Bq3XAAS

[image]